# How to formulate the probability of "selecting/applying functions to a number" in terms of random variables?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, solution-verification

> Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$ be some number.
>
> We assume that there exists a set of polynomials $\mathcal{F} = \{x,
>  x^2, x^3, \ldots, x^N\}$
>
> Suppose we draw a function $f \in \mathcal{F}$ from this set of
> polynomial then apply it to $x$. The probability of drawing a function
> is,
>
> $$\Pr[\text{$``f$ of degree $k$ is applied to $x"$}] = p_k, p_k \in
>  [0,1], k \in \{1, \ldots, N\}$$
>
> and we want to compute the expected value of applying $f$ to $x$.

My question is, how do we formulate this question in terms of random variables? i.e., I want to write the problem in the standard form, $\mathbb{E}_{X \sim P}[f(x)]$, How do we define this random variable, and how do we relate it to the probability? And how would we write the expectation of this random variable?

---

Here is my attempt: Let $X: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ be a random variable, with outcomes $\Omega = \{x, x^2, \ldots, x^N\} = \{f_1, f_2 \ldots, f_N\}$, where $f_k = x^k$. Then the expected value of applying these functions to $x$ is,
$$\mathbb{E}_{X \sim P}[f_k(x)] = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^N f_k(x) p_k$$
where $P$ is the probability mass function,
$$\Pr[X = f_k] = p_k$$ where $f_k$ is the polynomial of degree $k$ as above.

---

Do I have this formulated correctly?

Comment: You appear to be using $x$ to mean two different things (your fixed real number and the polynomial variable).  This is confusing.

Comment: Nor do I understand the question.  Let's call the fixed real number $\alpha$.  Then the possible values for $f(\alpha)$ are $\{\alpha, \alpha^2, \cdots, \alpha^n\}$ with known probabilities so you are just talking about a standard  discrete probability.  No?  (Note: I suppose there could be some confusion if two or more of the $\alpha^i$ coincide).

Comment: @lulu The problem is specified as drawing a function. By equivalence of events, it is the same as picking $\alpha$. I guess the space of the outcomes can just directly be the possible values.